# Submodule lattices of preprojective algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be a preprojective algebra of Dynkin type.

> Question 1: Let $P$ be an indecomposable projective $A$-module. It is known that the submodule lattice of $P$ is finite in Dynkin type $A_n$. Does this lattice have a concrete description or even a name? Has it been studied before?

> Question 2: Is it known for which projective modules $P$, the submodule lattice of $P$ is finite?

> Question 3: What is the best method (for example with QPA) to test whether the submodule lattice of a given module is distributive?

Comment: Just a comment: as long as you're working over an infinite field, the submodule lattice of a module over a finite dimensional algebra is finite if and only if it is distributive, and this happens if and only if there is no subquotient isomorphic to a direct sum of two isomorphic simple modules.

Comment: Wait, are you sure that the submodule lattice of any indecomposable projective is distributive? Look at $D_4$, with the central vertex numbered as $0$. I get that the indecomposable projective generated at the central vertex has a composition series with subquotients $(S_0, S_1, S_2, S_3, S_0, S_0, S_1, S_2, S_3, S_0)$. In particular, it has $S_0^2$ as a subquotient.

Comment: Here is what I suspect is going on.  Let $W$ be the Weyl group, let $W_i$ be the parabolic subgroup generated by $s_j$ for $j \neq i$. Let $w_0$ and $(w_0)_i$ be the maximal elements of $W$ and $W_i$ and put $w^i = w_0 (w_0)_i$. I suspect that $P_i$ has distributive submodule lattice iff $w^i$ is minuscule. In this sense, I suspect that the submodule lattice of $P_i$ is isomorphic to the lattice of order ideals in the heap of $w^i$. (continued)

Comment: See Stembridge 2001 https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.2000.8488 for the notions of "minuscule" and "heap", see Section 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.02490 for a recipe associating a preprojective module $\mathbb{C}H(w)$ to any minuscule element $w$ and see Prop 3.13 for the statement that the submodule lattice of  $\mathbb{C}H(w)$ is isomorphic to the lattice of order ideals in $H(w)$. I haven't yet found a reference that says that $\mathbb{C} H(w^i) \cong P_i$, but I think I can show this.

Comment: So I suspect the answer to (1) is "yes, the submodule lattice of $P_i$ is the lattice of order ideals in the heap $H(w^i)$, in the case that $w^i$ is minuscule, and it isn't distributive when $w^i$ is not minuscule". But, if you are sure that this lattice is always distributive, then I messed up in my computation above.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer thanks, I think you are right that it might not be finite in Dynkin type $D_n$ but it should be finite for type $A_n$. I edited my question.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer In type $A_n$ for small $n$, the computer gives me a bijection on the points of this lattice for a given indecomposable projective $P$. I wonder what this bijection is (it is not rowmotion on the points of the lattice as the computer bijection has fixed points).

Comment: Yes, in type $A_n$ I know what the indecomposable projectives look like, and they are these $\mathbb{C} H(w^i)$ modules. The heap poset in this case is the product of an $i-1$ chain and an $n-i$ chain, so the distributive lattice in question is the lattice of partitions contained in an $i \times (n+1-i)$ box.

Comment: Slide 19 at https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~bazse/minusculemultiples_slides.pdf states that $\mathbb{C}H(w^p)$ is $P_p$ when $w^p$ is minuscule. The heaps corresponding to (co)-minuscule weights have been extensively studied, there are analogues of partitions, SYT, promotion, etc for them. See Figures 3-7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608276 for pictures of these heaps in types ADE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an answer to question (2), strongly inspired by Dave Benson's comment:

**Theorem** Let $A$ be any ring and let $M$ be a finite length $A$-module. Then the lattice of $A$-submodules is distributive iff $M$ does not have a subquotient of the form $S^2$, for $S$ simple.

**Proof** First, suppose that $M$ has an $S^2$ subquotient, say $X \subset Y \subseteq M$ with $Y/X \cong S^2$. Then the interval $[X,Y]$ in the submodule lattice of $M$ is isomorphic to the submodule lattice of $S^2$. In particular, the submodule lattice of $S^2$ contains $S \oplus \boldsymbol{0}$, $\boldsymbol{0} \oplus S$ and $\Delta:= \{ (s,s) : s \in S \}$. Then $\{ \boldsymbol{0}, S \oplus \boldsymbol{0}, \boldsymbol{0} \oplus S, \Delta, S^2 \}$ form a copy of the [$M_3$ diamond lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties), which is not distributive.

Conversely, suppose that the submodule lattice of $M$ is not distributive. Then it [must contain either a copy of $M_3$ or $N_5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties). But the submodule lattice is [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice), so it cannot contain $N_5$, so it must contain $M_3$. In other words, there are submodules $X \subset W_1, W_2, W_3 \subset Y$ with $W_i \cap W_j = X$ and $W_i + W_j = Y$ for all $i \neq j$. Put $Z = Y/X$ and $V_i = W_i/X$. So $Z$ has submodules $V_i$ such that $W_i \cap W_j = \{ 0 \}$ and $W_i + W_j = Y/X$ for $i \neq j$. Then we have
$$V_2 \cong Z/V_1 \cong V_3 \cong Z/V_2 \cong V_1 \cong Z/V_3$$
so $V_1 \cong V_2 \cong V_3$ and $Z \cong V_1^2$. Let $S$ be a simple quotient of $V$, then $S^2$ is a quotient of $Z$ and is a subquotient of $Y/X$. $\square$

**Corollary:** The submodule lattice of $M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus M_r$ is distributive iff (1) the submodule lattice of each $M_i$ is individually distributive and (2) for $i \neq j$, the modules $M_i$ and $M_j$ have no common simple subquotient.

Now, in the preprojective Dynkin case, every simple module is a subquotient of every indecomposable projective module. So this simplifies to

**Corollary:** In the original Dynkin case that the OP asked about, if a projective module has distributive submodule lattice then it is indecomposable.

---

Here is the answer to question (1). The first thing to know is that the premise of the question is wrong: Indecomposable projectives do not always have a distributive submodule lattice. Rather, $P_i$ has a distributive submodule lattice if and only if the weight $\omega_i$ is minuscule. (Because we are in simply-laced type, "minuscule" and "co-minscule" are synonyms.) In this case, the submodule lattice of $P_i$ is isomorphic to the lattice of order ideals in the heap $H(w^i)$.

The minuscule weights have been classified: See Table 1 in [Thomas-Yong](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2469) and ignore the rows for types $B$ and $C$. The corresponding heaps are also well known; see the Figures in Section 2.2 of the Thomas-Yong paper.

---

I will now explain how to piece these results together, using facts from [Baumann and Kamnitzer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2469) and [Dranowski, Elek, Kamnitzer and Morton-Ferguson](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.02490).

We use the usual Coxeter notations: $\alpha_i$ are the simple roots, $s_i$ are the simple reflections and $\omega_i$ are the fundamental weights.

To every weight $\gamma$, Baumann and Kamnitzer define a preprojective module $N(\gamma)$, such that $N(\omega_i) = P_i$ (see Prop 10). Here are the key facts about $N(\gamma)$:

- If $\gamma$ is antidominant, then $N(\gamma) = 0$.
- If $s_j \gamma = \gamma + c \alpha_j$ for some $c \geq 0$, then we have a short exact sequence $0 \to N(\gamma) \to N(s_j \gamma) \to S_j^c \to 0$.
- As a corollary of the proceeding two statements, let $\gamma'$ be the unique antidominant weight in the same orbit as $\gamma$ and let $\gamma - \gamma' = \sum d_i \alpha_i$. Then $N(\gamma)$ has dimension $(d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n)$.
- Let $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ be as in the previous bullet point, and let $\gamma' = - \sum c_i \omega_i$. Then $N(\gamma)$ is uniquely characterized as the only preprojective module with dimension $(d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n)$ and socle of dimension $(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$.

Now, let $\omega'_i$ be the unique fundamental weight so that $-\omega'_i$ and $\omega_i$ are in the same orbit. Let $w^i$ be the Coxeter group element of minimal length such that $w^i \omega_i = - \omega'_i$ and let $s_{j_1} s_{j_2} \cdots s_{j_L}$ be a reduced word for $w^i$. Put $\gamma(k) = s_{j_k} \cdots s_{j_2} s_{j_1} (- \omega'_i)$, so $\gamma(0) = - \omega'_i$, $\gamma(L) = \omega_i$ and $\gamma(k) = \gamma(k-1) + c_k \alpha_{i_k}$ for some integer $c_k$; it turns out (proof omitted) that $c_k>0$. So the modules $N(\gamma(k))$ form a filtration of $N(\omega_i) = P_i$, with subquotients $S_{j_k}^{c_k}$.

In particular, if any $c_k$ is $\geq 2$, then the submodule lattice of $P_i$ is not distributive.

If all the $c_k$ are $1$, then $w^i$ is what is called $\omega_i$-minuscule (see Definition 2.4 in [Dranowski, Elek, Kamnitzer and Morton-Ferguson](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.02490)), and is therefore minuscule, and the results of that paper apply. I'll summarize those results now.

We define a poset $H(w^i)$, called the heap of $w^i$, as follows: The ground set of $H(w^i)$ is $[L]$. The order relation is the transitive closure of the following: $a \prec b$ if $a<b$ and $s_{j_a} s_{j_b} \neq s_{j_b} s_{j_a}$. We have the following:

- $H(w^i)$ indexes a basis for $\mathbb{C} H(w^i)$. To understand the maps in $\mathbb{C} H(w^i)$, take the Hasse diagram of $H(w^i)$ (see the Thomas-Yong paper) and place $1$'s and $-1$'s on the edges in order to make the preprojective relations hold.
- Order ideals of $H(w^i)$ correspond to submodules of $\mathbb{C} H(w^i)$. These also correspond to the weak order interval $[e, w^i]$, and to roots in the $W$ orbit of $\omega_i$.
- The submodule lattice of $\mathbb{C}H(w^i)$ is the lattice of order ideals in $H(w^i)$.
- Total orders of $H(w^i)$ correspond to reduced words for $w^i$, which correspond to composition series of $P_i$.

In type $A_n$, $H(w^i)$ is the product of an $i$-vertex chain and an $(n+1-i)$ vertex chain. Order ideals correspond to partitions fitting in an $i \times (n+1-i)$ box, and the submodule lattice is this part of Young's lattice. Total orders on $H(w^i)$ are standard Young tableaux of shape $i \times (n+1-i)$.